# VB.net data retrieval and display

Tags: mysql, vb.net

So, for some reason I can't work out I think the below is only retrieving the 1st letter of the value within the column I'm trying to search. (**Note**: the database is called m1 and contains 11 columns in total).

I tested the query first in SQL Admin and it worked properly (I think).

[image]

I then wrote this myself using documentation, I think I've more that likely made a mistake somewhere..

```
Dim hostnameQuery As String = "SELECT `HOSTNAME` FROM `m1` WHERE 1"
    Dim SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.connStr)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(hostnameQuery, SQLConnection)

    Try
        SQLConnection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            main.Label64.Text = (reader.GetChar(0))
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    Finally
        SQLConnection.Close()

    End Try
```

I added this to a button click so when I click the button only the letter 'M' appears but the value is 'M1'

[image]

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you requested only a character. Try using `GetString()` instead of `GetChar()` :

```
main.Label64.Text = (reader.GetString(0))
```

Comment: God, I knew it would be simple...- Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that can be improved in your code.

First of all, you can remove the condition `WHERE 1`, because it means "EVERYTHING" so it is not useful.

Secondly, you can avoid calling `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` because it is usually used to run an instruction that does not return anything (like `INSERT`).

Finally, if you are interested only to the first returned row, you can avoid the `While` loop and use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` instead.

To summarize, instead of:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
While reader.Read
    main.Label64.Text = (reader.GetChar(0))
End While
```

simply do this:

```
main.Label64.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
```